# Powershell Funciones. Consulta ForEach + If, Condición Inadecuada

Tags: funciones, sql, powershell

Estoy buscando la forma de consultar en powershell los procesos que tiene activos cada usuario del AD en un Windows Server 2019 creando un array con los usuarios cuyo Enabled sea "True" y haciendo iterar la búsqueda de varios factores de los procesos (nombre, Id, cpu, etc.) divididos en dos consultas para que no salga una tabla demasiado grande y sea más visible.
Mi problema es que, teniendo el array, y funcionando el Foreach, no encuentro la forma de condicionar la búsqueda de los procesos según el nombre de usuario en cada paso del bucle. Lo he probado con un if como el de abajo, con where como pipe de cada consulta,... pero no lo he podido resolver. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

[image: Código, varias versiones]

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores.  Me parece que necesitas

```
($usuario.name -eq username)
```

en vez de

```
($usuario.name = username)
```

Pero hay otros errores.

Comment: Dentro del if no me deja utilizar $usuario.name, "no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet". Estoy dudando hasta de la lógica del planteamiento.